# VB.NET How To Tell If New Class Instance Was Ended Early?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, class

I'm trying to detect if the Sub New() in my class has ended early due to missing fields. Below is a sample of my code:

```
Class Account
    Public Sub New(ByVal Firstname As String, ByVal LastName As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Email As String, ByVal Password As String)
        ' Check For Blank Fields
        If Firstname = "" Or LastName = "" Or Username = "" Or Email = "" Or Password = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter All Information Requested")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Set Public Variables Of Class
        Firstname = Firstname
        LastName = LastName
        Username = Username
        Email = Email
        Password = Password
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub OtherUse()

    End Sub
End Class
' Create New Instance
Dim Process As New Account(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text)
' HERE - How Can I Catch The Early Exit From The Instance Due To Potential Missing Fields?

' Use Instance For Other Use
Process.OtherUse()
```

How would I catch the Exit Sub from the class in the parent form to prevent the further processing of Process.OtherUse()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're approaching this problem the wrong way. Validate the input first, and then once the input is valid, create a new Account using `New`.

Another option would be to initialize data in New without checking if it's valid or not, then have an `IsValid` method in that class that you would call from another class to know whether or not the messagebox should be shown.

One way or another, the Account class shouldn't be responsible for a UI concern like showing a MessageBox on the screen. And the constructor should only be responsible for constructing the object, not validating the input, because you can't "abort" a constructor. You have a reference to a new object even though you call `Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 1):

A fourth alternative, in addition to the three mentioned by Meta-Knight:

Have the constructor **throw an exception** when the parameters aren’t valid.

As an aside, your use of `Or`, while working, is a logical error: `And` and `Or` are *bitwise arithmetic* operations. You want a logical operation, `OrElse` (there’s also `AndAlso`). These may seem similar to `Or` and `And` and in this particular case, both happen to work. But they are actually quite different semantically, bitwise operations are just wrong here (it’s a pity that this code even compiles. The compiler shouldn’t allow this).

Comment: And and Or are also Boolean operators that don't short circuit in VB.

Comment: @Chris But not for any good reason. They shouldn’t be defined that way.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the OrElse operator but couldn't think of it off the top of my head, was thinking of AndOr for some reason! Changed it over now :)